# Geometric-probability. Two numbers $x$ and $y$ are chosen at random within the unit interval $[0, 1]$.

Tags: probability, geometric-probability

Two numbers $x$ and $y$ are chosen at random within the unit interval $[0, 1]$. What is the probability that the sum of these is greater than one and that the sum of their squares is less than one?

The following must be complied with: $x+y>1$ and $x^2+y^2<1$. We plot, and there is an area between these two. The problem I have is in calculating that area.

[image]

Comment: It's the difference of areas of a circular sector and a right-angled triangle.

Comment: It is a quarter circle of radius one less a right angled triangle of side one. ${ \pi \over 4} - { 1 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to compute the area of your blue region. It equals $$\int_0^1  \sqrt{1-x^2}\,{\rm d}x -\frac{1}{2}.$$And you don't even need to do calculus for that, geometrically you know that $$\int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,{\rm d}x = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \pi \cdot 1^2 = \frac{\pi}{4}.$$The probability is just $$\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2} = \frac{\pi-2}{4}.$$

Answer (score 3):

As is mentioned in the comments this is a neat result.

If you want to calculate the area of a [circular segment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_segment#:%7E:text=More%20formally%2C%20a%20circular%20segment,the%20endpoints%20of%20the%20arc.) then you can notice that is equal to the area of a [circular sector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_sector) minus an iscoceles triangle.

In this case the radius of the circle is $1$ and the sector is $\frac{1}{4}$ of the entire circle so it has area $\frac{\pi}{4}$. On the other hand the triangle is a right triangle with legs of length $1$, so it has area $\frac{1}{2}$.

Therefore the area of the segment is $\frac{\pi}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \approx 0.285398$

Comment: Quick sanity-check: maybe you meant $0.285398$ instead? A probability cannot be bigger than $1$.

Comment: I was just thinking of it as an area so I didn't realize that, but you're correct. Thanks !